# Tar directory to file in the directory being tar'ed

Tags: linux, unix, disk-space, tar, inode

I have a mount-point, `/media/xvdf1` which I use `bindfs` to mount at `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs` with user/group `jenkins`. I wish to back it up, but I do not have enough space on the other partition. After tarring, the file should be uploaded to S3 using `aws s3 cp`.

My problem is that I if I use tar to create the archive, it tries to tar the file that it is writing to.

Isn't there a way have tar avoid tarring its own output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--exclude=pattern` if you need to, though I'm not sure how you're doing where you need to do this.

Running the following:

```
tar -cf test.tar .
```

I get the message:

```
tar: ./test.tar: file is the archive; not dumped
```

but perhaps that's just a GNU extension, though my BSD version gives a similar

```
tar: ./test.tar: Can't add archive to itself
```

Still, you could tell it explicitly to ignore it with

```
tar -cf test.tar --exclude=./test.tar .
```

Comment: The reason it does not detect the problem is probably because of the bindfs mount.

Answer (score 2):

I meet a similar problem too.

It may works like this, in the example

```
tar -cf test.tar .
```

You are asking `tar` to archive `.`, then `tar` create an "empty" file `test.tar` to store the content. But the *point* is that `test.tar` is also part of the directory `.`. It looks a little like infinite recursive. Anyhow, `tar` seems pretty smart and prevent that, since in most case that is not what you want.

Besides using `--exclude`, you can also try

```
tar -cf test.tar ./*
```

In this way, you are asking `tar` to archive (almost) all files in `.` *before* the command runs, note that `test.tar` is not included.